# DART pub get failed after update from 1.60 to 1.72: Failed to precompile intl:extract_to_arb

Tags: dart, dart2js

Last night, I accidentally updated my Dart Editor and SDK version from 1.60 to 1.72. Accidentally meaning I didn't want to change my development environment while I was developing, but it happened. After that, I see this when I try to "pub get":

```
>--- 7:48:46 AM Running pub get on /Users/Clayvessel/Dropbox/PROJECT/DART/DART_Project/OneViewer_Composite-Viewer/OneViewer_6 ... ---
>Resolving dependencies...
>Got dependencies!
>Precompiling executables...
>Loading source assets...
>Failed to precompile intl:extract_to_arb:
>Unhandled exception:
>Uncaught Error: Failure getting http://localhost:51271/packages/intl/extract_messages.dart: 404 Not Found
>Stack Trace:
>#0      _asyncLoadError (dart:_builtin:285)
>#1      _httpGet.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:_builtin:228)
>#2      _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1078)
>#3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:390)
>#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399)
>#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:290)
>#6      _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:110)
>#7      _handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:178)
>#8      _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1078)
>#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:390)
>#10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399)
>#11     _DelayedDone.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:614)
>#12     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:711)
>#13     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:671)
>#14     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
>#15     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
>#16     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
>#17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)
>
>#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:883)
>#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
>#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
>#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
>#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)
>Failed to precompile intl:generate_from_arb:
>Unhandled exception:
>Uncaught Error: Failure getting http://localhost:51271/packages/intl/extract_messages.dart: 404 Not Found
>Stack Trace:
>#0      _asyncLoadError (dart:_builtin:285)
>#1      _httpGet.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:_builtin:228)
>#2      _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1078)
>#3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:390)
>#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399)
>#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:290)
>#6      _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:110)
>#7      _handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:178)
>#8      _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1078)
>#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:390)
>#10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399)
>#11     _DelayedDone.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:614)
>#12     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:711)
>#13     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:671)
>#14     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
>#15     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
>#16     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
>#17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)
>
>#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:883)
>#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
>#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
>#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
>#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)
```

**Specifically it is complaining about the two things:**

1. import 'package:chart/chart.dart'
2. import 'package:chrome/chrome_app.dart' as chrome

They were working just fine before I update Dart SDK. In Dart Editor, it complains:
Target of URI does not exist

As a novice in Dart, I have done exhaustive searches and din't have a luck. Deadline is coming and I anxiously looking for a solution to this. I develop on Mac Book. But I have a Windows 7 notebook as well. They are sharing project folders equipped by Dropbox. Yesterday before this error happen, I updated my OS X to Yosemite. While the machine was updating, I tried to pub get and compile dart2js for my project in Windows 7 notebook. It generated some errors. So I deleted my whole Dart folder and downloaded it again now from Mac Book. And I realised now dart has been updated to 1.7.2.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

On the command line, running "pub cache repair" might help. I frequently have to do this when I update.

Comment: Thank you so much! "pub cache repair" was exactly what I was looking for. It magically resolved all the issues. After 10 hours of work to fix this issue and I was exhausted. But you saved my life. Thank you again!

Comment: This did the trick for me also... I wish I could accept the answer myself. Up voted at least :-). Thanks!